# Can you reset Python's sys.path?

Tags: python

I've been doing some work with Python, and I believe my sys.path has "lost" entries. Specifically, I can import no libraries whatsoever (it works if I place them in the folder with the program, but placing it within Python's library directory doesn't work).

Presumably, it has forgotten what folders to look in, and I would like to know how to set sys.path back to it's default values.

Edit: Win7, 32-bit. Yes, I've tried reinstalling (and repairing) Python.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.path` is read from the [environment variable PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).  Check to see what the environment variable is, and reset it if needed.

Note that a python script could re-define `sys.path`.

Comment: I know how to check sys.path's contents, and I know how to change them. The problem is that I don't know what all of the default values are - I could add entries, sure, but it would just be haphazard guesses.

Comment: If you've clobbered the environment variable PYTHONPATH, and want to restore it, it's probably easiest to just re-install python.  If you want people to say what their paths are, providing your OS would be useful, and I guess the could assume you used standard install options . . .

Comment: When reinstalling, remember to delete %PYTHONPATH% first.

Comment: sys.path != PYTHONPATH